# How to make Three.js fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, fullscreen, three.js

I want to make a game with Three.js, but how do I make it fullscreen? I saw [this article](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/11/17/lets-make-a-3d-game-make-it-fullscreen), and I've included THREEx in my code, but when I do this: `THREEx.FullScreen.request()` nothing happens! I looked at the THREEx code, and changed it like this, for the purposes of debugging:

```
THREEx.FullScreen.request   = function(element)
{
    element = element   || document.body;
    if( this._hasWebkitFullScreen ){
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        console.log("f");
    }else if( this._hasMozFullScreen ){
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        console.log("g");
    }else{
        console.assert(false);
    }
}
```

So, this defaults to making document.body fullscreen, and it prints "f" in the console. But - nothing! There are no error messages in the console or anything... And I've tried his pool example, it works, so I'm pretty sure that it's not my computer's fault...

Comment: When are you calling it? I believe you're only allowed to request as a reaction to user input such as the `keydown` event.

Comment: Really? That's strange, I don't get it... But will do!

Comment: When I write it like this: `document.addEventListener("keydown", THREEx.FullScreen.request);`, I get an error that "assertion failed."

Comment: You can't request the document to go fullscreen as it isn't an element. Try `document.body`.

Comment: I'm not, the code defaults to making the body fullscreen if no other element is supplied.

Comment: The function uses `this` which will (incorrectly) be the document if you pass the function directly. Try `function() { THREEx.FullScreen.request(); }` (it is different).

Comment: Great, it works now! Please, answer the question with that snippet of code and so on, so I can accept it.

Comment: Here is my answer to similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53585584/2573640

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to:

1. Request when the user allows to, e.g. on `keydown`. I guess the reasoning is the same as opening popups. A web page toggling fullscreen randomly of its own accord is arguably even more annoying than popups opening automatically.
2. Request fullscreen on an element, not `document`.
3. Call `request` with `this` set to `THREEx.FullScreen` (so just call it like below).

So e.g.:

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  THREEx.FullScreen.request();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode: 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });
```

..then 'm' toggles fullscreen.